# Signing a VSTO Excel Add-in, targeting .NET Framework 4.0, using a SHA-2 certificate

Tags: excel, .net-4.0, vsto, digital-signature, sha256

I have a VSTO 2010 Excel add-in, targeting .Net Framework 4.0, Visual Studio 2010.

We were using a SHA-1 certificate for the past few years for signing the manifest and the assemblies. The application has been deployed for a lot of end-users. Now with the SHA-1 deprecation policy coming into effect from January 2016, the renewed certificate that has been issued by the CA is keyed using SHA-256.

Please have a look at the files generated by building a Excel 2010 VSTO Add-in, using various versions of Visual Studio:

NOTE: The certificate used for all the following cases is keyed using SHA-2 algorithm.

**.VSTO generated by VS 2010 SP1, Target Framework 4.0:**

The `DigestMethod` Algorithm mentioned for the `dependentAssembly`'s `hash` is SHA1, even when SHA2 certificate was used.

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="ExcelAddIn1.dll.manifest" size="18274">
    <assemblyIdentity name="ExcelAddIn1.dll" version="1.0.0.1" publicKeyToken="2142698160a31911" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
    <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>DIGEST VALUE</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Under `publisherIdentity` tag, the `SignatureMethod` and the `DigestMethod` used is **SHA256**, which is according to the certificate's algorithm.

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256" />

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
```

**.VSTO generated by VS 2013 SP4 and VS 2015, Target Framework 4.0:**

Please note the algorithm mentioned in `<dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />` tag is **SHA1**. Which is same as what gets generated by VS 2010.

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="ExcelAddIn1.dll.manifest" size="16058">
    <assemblyIdentity name="ExcelAddIn1.dll" version="1.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="2142698160a31911" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
    <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>DIGEST VALUE</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Similarly, under `publisherIdentity` tag, `SignatureMethod` and `DigestMethod` are still using **SHA1**. The .vsto file build using VS 2010 and VS 2013 SP1 are having **SHA2** here.

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
```

*Will this work/be supported even after January 2016/17?*

**.VSTO generated by VS 2013 SP4 and VS 2015, Target Framework 4.5.2:**

Please note the algorithm mentioned in `<dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha2" />` tag is **SHA2**.

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="ExcelAddIn1.dll.manifest" size="16058">
    <assemblyIdentity name="ExcelAddIn1.dll" version="1.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="2142698160a31911" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
    <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
             <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha2" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>DIGEST VALUE</dsig:DigestValue>
    </hash>
</dependentAssembly>
```

`SignatureMethod` and `DigestMethod` are now indicating **SHA2** algorithm.

```
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha2" />

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha2" />
```

It seems that the update in VS 2013 SP3 (also available in VS 2015) is using/enforcing the algorithm as per the .Net Framework being targeted.

For .Net Framework 4.0, the DigestMethod and SigntureMethod are always SHA1, irrespective of the certificate used. Now the add-in works on machine having only .Net 4.0 as the VSTO/clickonce loader does not have to deal with SHA2 at all.

So, considering that SHA-2 certificates have to be used starting January 2016, what should be the configuration used for signing the add-in with SHA-2 certificate?

1. VS 2010, .Net Framework 4.0 and SHA-2 certificate *(Does not work without .Net Framework 4.5 or newer installed on the machine)*
2. VS 2015, .Net Framework 4.0 and SHA-2 certificate *(This is no different from using SHA-1 certificates. The VSTO files have only SHA-1 entries, not sure whether this will work after January 2016)*
3. VS 2015, .Net Framework 4.5.2 and SHA-2 certificate *(Not suitable for me. I need to keep the target framework as 4.0)*

I am installing the Excel add-ins on machines offline. They are always loaded from the file system.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\ExcelAddin1]
"Description"="ExcelAddin1 - COM add-in created with Visual Studio Tools for Office"
"FriendlyName"="ExcelAddin1"
"Manifest"="file:///C:/published/Addins/ExcelAddin1.vsto|vstolocal"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Link to same question posted on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ae7ab48c-ae1d-44a9-b96e-f2ba8e8fced1/signing-a-vsto-2010-excel-addin-targeting-net-framework-40-using-a-sha2-certificate?forum=vsto)